# Writing a CSV file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to save in a CVS file some information using Python.

When I run it, it looks like it works but when I go to the file nothing comes out

This is my code:

```
dic = {"name": "jason", "name": "mike"}
file = "names.csv"
cvs = open(file, "a")
column = "name,name2\n"
cvs.write(column)
for key in dic.keys():
    name = key
    name2 = dic[key]
    fil = name + "," + name2 + "\n"
    cvs.write(fil)
```

Answer (score 0):

(it's `csv`, not `cvs`. CSV is comma-separated-value, CVS is a drugstore).

You're never closing the file. Just put a

```
cvs.close()
```

at the end of your code and it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
import csv

data = {'name':'jason','name':'mike'}
with open('names.csv', 'w+') as csvf:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvf, fieldnames=['name'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for key, value in data.items():
        writer.writerow(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, a serious problem -- you can't have the same key multiple times in a dict! You could have {'names': ['Mike', 'Jason']} but as is, one will be re-written by the other. This may be part of your issue.

Second, in general, it is much easier to do csv creation through pandas, with functions such as `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict` -- way easier, way less error prone, etc -- in fact I STRONGLY advise against writing such files manually. (Although this is about ALL I like pandas for.)

```
correctDict = {'names': ['Mike', 'Jason']}
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(correctDict)
df.to_csv('myFile.csv')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html